# Problem with compiling of ASP.NET Core sources from "blazor-united-end" branch

Tags: asp.net, compilation, blazor

I get errors during compilation of ASP.NET Core sources (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore, version: .NET 8.0) compilation of branch “blazor-united-end” (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/danroth27/blazor-united-end).

I've followed instructions from `/docs/BuildFromSource.md` then used the script from `/eng/build.ps1`. After a few code modifications, I’ve reached successful compilation by `/eng/build.ps1` script. Unfortunately, I have errors with visual studio compilation. The errors for example in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` project are:

```
"D:\repo\aspnetcore_danroth27\blazor-united-end\src\Components\Authorization\src\AuthorizeViewCore.cs(83,164,83,192): error CS0103: The name 'CascadingAuthenticationState' does not exist in the current context 
1>D:\repo\aspnetcore_danroth27\blazor-united-end\src\Components\Authorization\src\AuthorizeRouteView.cs(81,35,81,63): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CascadingAuthenticationState' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>D:\repo\aspnetcore_danroth27\blazor-united-end\src\Components\Authorization\src\AuthorizeRouteView.cs(82,44,82,72): error CS0103: The name 'CascadingAuthenticationState' does not exist in the current context
```

It looks like that `CascadingAuthenticationState.razor` wasn't compiled to `CascadingAuthenticationState.cs`.

I’ve also got following warnings:

```
7>The analyzer assembly ‘C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3\\Sdks\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\\codestyle\\cs\\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeStyle.dll’ references version ‘4.8.0.0’ of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version ‘4.5.0.0’.  
7>The analyzer assembly ‘C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3\\Sdks\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\\codestyle\\cs\\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.dll’ references version ‘4.8.0.0’ of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version ‘4.5.0.0’.  
7>The analyzer assembly ‘C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3\\Sdks\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\\source-generators\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll’ references version ‘4.7.0.0’ of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version ‘4.5.0.0’.
```

Any idea how to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. The problem was in used SDK version. In branch: `blazor-united-end` the desired (on start, after downloading solution) is `8.0.100-alpha.1.22531.1`. But this version in unavailable to download. On default the system in case the absence of desired version has choosen `8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3`. But it hasn't been the correct version. I had to choose SDK on my own. The nearest, downloable version is `8.0.100-preview.1.23115.2`. So I've download it and change the `global.json` file, in which SDK is defined. I present the fragment of `global.json` below

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "8.0.100-preview.1.23115.2"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet": "8.0.100-preview.1.23115.2",
  (...)
```